# p-norm preserving matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

I am reading [Scott Aaronson, Is Quantum Mechanics An Island In Theoryspace?](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401062) In Section 2 Other p-Norms,
he tries to prove for $p>2$, the p-norm preserving matrix is generalized diagonal. Namely, for matrix $A=[a_{j,k}]_{j,k=1}^n$,
$$\sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^p=\sum_{j=1}^n\Big|\sum_{k=1}^n a_{j,k}x_k\Big|^p\,\,\forall (x_j)_{j=1}^n \implies [a_{j,k}] \text{ is a generalized diagonal matrix}$$
I am not sure what exactly a generalized diagonal matrix is. I first guessed it was a permutation matrix with its $1$'s replaced by another number, then I surmised it was a permutation matrix with its $1$'s replaced by $\pm1$'s. He proves this for separate cases. I am having trouble understanding his step for when $p$ is an odd positive integer.

He "claim that, so long as $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are nonnegative, the entries of $Ax$ never change sign." First I do not quite understand what he means by changing signs. I suppose he means the sign of each number $\sum_{j=1}^n a{j,k}x^{(1)}_k$ is the same as that of number $\sum_{j=1}^n a{j,k}x^{(2)}_k$ $\forall j$ but different vectors $x^{(1)}_k\neq x^{(2)}_k$. I am do not understand where $(s_j)_j$ comes from. It does not look like it is just $s_j=\text{sgn}y_j$. I would appreciate if someone can elucidate.

Comment: There are simpler proofs. See https://mathoverflow.net/q/288052

Comment: Yes, also the result in the paper by Aaronson is just not correct. The so-called "generalized diagonal matrices" are *not* norm preserving in general. The norm preserving matrices are some sort of permutation matrices where the 1 entries can also be equal -1.

Comment: @KBS: Right. Can you make sense of his proof, if we correct the proposition?

Comment: @Hans. No, I have tried to understand and what is not doing is not clear at all. Mixing that with the fact that the considered type of matrices the author is considering is simply not correct, does not make me very trustful in the whole paper. If I were you I would focus on another paper/proof that is more serious.